# symetric div with background image without clip-path

Tags: html, css

hi guys i have two differents div with background image, as you see in the picture. They are symetrics. i achieved that with clip-path, but as know it's not well supported by all browsers, could you guys give me an alternative to achieve that to be more compatible. Your help would be appreciated. Thx!

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  /* background: red; */
  padding: 100px 0;
}

.container_first {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 14%, 100% 90%, 0% 100%);
  background-image: url(images/img12.jpg);
  min-height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.container_second {
  margin-top: -54px;

  clip-path: polygon(0% 10%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 86%);
  background-image: url(images/img22.jpg);
  min-height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use skew transformation:

```css
.first,
.second {
  height:300px;
  transform-origin:left;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.first {
  transform:skewY(4deg);
}
.first > div {
  height:100%;
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/800/800) center/cover;
  transform:skewY(-4deg);
  transform-origin:left;
}
.second {
  transform:skewY(-4deg);
}
.second > div {
  height:100%;
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1045/800/800) center/cover;
  transform:skewY(8deg); /* twice the skew here so you may need another skew for the content*/
  transform-origin:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="second">
  <div></div>
</div>
```