# How can I rotate my background and cut out the part that would stand out of the device width?

Tags: html, css, rotation, css-transforms

So basically I want to have a rotated background on mobile.
I've tried using

```
transform: rotate(15deg);
```

But whenever I do that, the width of the body gets bigger and I have tried using things like

```
overflow: hidden;
```

but that didn't work.
So I wanted to know, how I can rotate my background/background-color.

[image: Rotated Background with different sections]

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59127204/8620333

Answer (score -1):

If you use this CSS, it will automatically adjust the background to the viewer to fit their screen(responsive)

```
<style>
body {
  background-image: url("example.jpg"); /* The image used */
  background-color: #cccccc; /* Used if the image is unavailable */
  background-position: center; /* Center the image */
  background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Do not repeat the image */
  background-size: cover; /* Resize the background image to cover the entire container */      
  background-attachment: fixed; /* makes the background position fixed */
}
</style>
<html>
<body>
<!-- put your html here !-->
</body>
</html>
```

I suppose this is better than rotating the background but if you really want to rotate the background you can use something like this I think.

```
<style>
body {
  background-image: url("example.jpg"); /* The image used */
  background-color: #cccccc; /* Used if the image is unavailable */
  background-position: center; /* Center the image */
  background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Do not repeat the image */
  background-size: cover; /* Resize the background image to cover the entire container */      
  background-attachment: fixed; /* makes the background position fixed */
  transform: rotate(15deg);
}
</style>
<html>
<body>
<!-- put your html here !-->
</body>
</html>
```